# Passing parameters from page navigation and binding them to webbrowser in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, webbrowser-control

I have 2 pages. Page1 wants to navigate to Page 2 using:

```
 private void listbox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = listbox1.SelectedIndex;
            String pom = "";
            RssDataSet ob = lista.ElementAt(index);
            pom = pom + ob.description;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/novaStrana.xaml?id="+pom, UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

It's basically taking the index from the listbox1, getting some info about it from ob and navigating to Page2.

Here's the problem now: I can't get my "pom" parameter on Page2. Basically my OnNavigatedTo method is not firing. The Page2 page looks as follows:

```
public novaStrana()
        {

            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            String stuff = "";
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            string msg = "";

             if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))
            {

                stuff = msg;
            }
        }
```

Why is it not firing at all? I know this because I tried debugging loads of times.

I run the emulator, click on my list item, the debugger shows me that Page2 is being initialised meaning the constructor is running, but once the constructor is done that's it. Page2 doesn't even reach OnNavigatedTo.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
Page2:

```
namespace ZaParsiranje
{
    public partial class novaStrana : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        public novaStrana()
        {

             InitializeComponent();            
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            String stuff = "";
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            string msg = "";

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("id", out msg))
            {

                stuff = msg;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

And the xalm of Page2:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="ZaParsiranje.novaStrana"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"  
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
            <phone:WebBrowser Name="WebBroser1" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: review ur code once, u will find where is the problem !

Comment: What do you mean by review exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry @AshokDamani, but your comment seems quite useless.. What a pity that it is not possible to "-1" a comment..

Comment: No honestly, the only reason I'm posting here is because I've been wrecking my brain over it. Yes I'm a beginner at this. If you're such an experienced developer why don't you just guide me!

Comment: @user1991181 have u got the point or not ?

Comment: I dont need to, I've noticed it too. That does not change that your comment is not helpful. The solution is, comment - not.

Comment: @Ashok Damani. Look at the comment to your answer please.

Comment: I don't know if they will be helpful, but check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13660324/717732 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466191/onnavigatedto-mysteriously-not-firing-on-windows-phone-7

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I saw them before I posted this question and just reread them. Thanks for the effort, but I'm not finding anything useful. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't get my "pom" parameter on Page2

You are trying to get the value of QueryString by `"msg"` while you are storing it with `"id"` key. How could you expect to get the right result?

Just correct your code:

```
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("id", out msg))
{
    stuff = msg;
}
```

**EDIT**

or the way to get the `queryString` :

get it within ur constructor

```
public novaStrana()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            

            Loaded += (o, e) =>
            {
                  if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("id", out msg))
                  {
                        stuff = msg;
                  }
            }

        }
```

where `stuff` & `msg` are defined outside of the constructor (within ur class).

Comment: Reviewing my question once, you'll find out exactly what you're missing here. My OnNavigatedTo is not being fired.

Comment: @user1991181: that's not that clear. I was just about to ask if the NavigatedTo is executed at all when Ashok responded. "Not firing" could refer to anything. As you see, Ashok also did not notice that. Please clarify that section of the question.

Comment: Right, I run the emulator, click on my list item, the debugger shows me that Page2 is being initialised meaning the constructor is running, but once the constructor is done that's it. Page2 doesn't even reach OnNavigatedTo :/

Comment: Ok! So **include this description** in the question. Right now, your question looks like "why I dont get my parameter" and Ashok responded perfectly to that. Please edit the question and the title accordingly.

Comment: @user1991181 then i cant seems to find where is the problem with the piece of code u'v provided

Comment: What exactly would you like me to post? the xaml or the cs? And which page would you like me to do that for?

Comment: it'll better to post the whole cs class.

Comment: Just did. I get a NullReferenceException on if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("id", out msg))

Comment: The debugger skips Loaded += (o, e) =>
            {
                  if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("id", out msg))
                  {
                        stuff = msg;
                  }
            } entirely.